# Advertise option is not available on my Amazon Developer Console

Tags: amazon-appstore

When I go in the promotions section on Amazon developer console, it only shows me the price cut option... Option for Advertise is not available... Is there any solution for this, or any one has faced this issue.

Here's the ss from my console:
[My Amazon Developer Console Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoMOm.png)

I tried to start a ppc compaign for my app. but I am unable to select an option...